# error connecting with ssl delphi 2007 indy 10

Tags: delphi, openssl, indy10

I am new to Delphi and I am assigned with a Delphi 2007 desktop application and have been asked to enable https in that application current it uses Indy 10.1.5.

Below is the code which I have written but could not get expected output.

I am not sure if the DLLs that I use are compatible with it or not.

Error I get is **"error connecting with ssl"**

```
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
Id_HandlerSocket : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;                         
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    with IdHTTP do
    begin
      Name := 'IdHTTP';
      AllowCookies := True;
      RedirectMaximum := 25;
      ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := False;
      ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 0;
      Request.ContentLength := -1;
      Request.Accept := 'text/html, */*';
      Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
      Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)';
      HTTPOptions :=      [hoForceEncodeParams];
    end;
    Id_HandlerSocket := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
    Id_HandlerSocket.SSLOptions.Method :=  sslvSSLv23;           
    Id_HandlerSocket.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
    //     Id_HandlerSocket.Port:= 443 ;
    IdHTTP.IOHandler := Id_HandlerSocket;
    try
      Result := IdHTTP.Get('https://'+WebServer+'/myfol/test_file.txt');  // this is the place where I get error
    except on E : Exception do
      Begin
        Result := E.Message +' ||  '+E.ClassName   ;
      End
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: *I am not sure if the DDLs that I use are compatible with it or not.* As you did not say which `dll`s you use, it's hard for everybody else too. Version 10.1.5 sounds awfully old, but then again, I'm not sure if the latest version works with Delphi 7. Anyway there are plenty of q/a on this site regarding *error connecting with ssl*. I just searched that exact phrase and got 71 matches. Do that search and list them `Newest first`. There are good chances that you find the answer. I don't close this question (as a duplicate), because your combination may require some extra attention. Good luck.

Comment: That is not enough information to diagnose your problem with. Which *EXACT* DLLs are you using? What is the `Exception`'s actual class name and complete error message? There should be more details provided in the exception about the actual OpenSSL error. Also, you really should not be using `Method := sslvSSLv23` on the SSLIOHandler. 10.1.5 is an *extremely* old version of Indy. The current version is 10.6.2, you should consider upgrading. It is very likely that such an old version simply won't ever be able to connect to modern servers, especially ones that require TLS 1.2 SNI extensions

Comment: @Remy A quick q regarding newest Indy and newest OpenSLLs: How far back (in Delphi versions) are they backward compatible?

Comment: @TomBrunberg "*I'm not sure if the latest version works with Delphi 7*" - yes, it does, for now. There are plans to drop it in Indy 11, but there is no ETA on that right now.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Indy 10 supports back to Delphi 6, maybe 5 with some tweaks. Indy 11 will drop support for 2007 and earlier.

Comment: can you please help me which the process/steps to upgrade indy. @Remy

Comment: @Aaron http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx

Comment: Consider using the WinHttp API if you just need a HTTPS safe connection.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez can u tell me how.? because i just need to get a file from a server

Comment: @Aaron asking for tutorials is off-topic for StackOverflow. There are plenty of tutorials available on MSDN and elsewhere for WinInet and WinHTTP examples. Search around and do some research.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delphi+winhttp is a good start ;)